Interpreting log likelihood in a spatial panel model in R
Calculating a spatial panel model in R using the splm package:
library(splm)
library(spdep)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> Loading required package: spData
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
data("Produc", package = "Ecdat")
data("usaww")

usalw <- mat2listw(usaww)

fm <- log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp

respatlag <- spml(fm, data = Produc, listw = spdep::mat2listw(usaww),
                  model="random", spatial.error="none", lag=TRUE)

generates an estimate of log likelihood in the model object:
respatlag$logLik
#> [1] 1426.577

However, this log likelihood is a positive number. I have also gotten a positive number using other data, but this reprex is provided.
Most log likelihood values are usually negative. This Cross-Validated post says that log likelihoods can be positive, but does not provide further detail on interpretation. I am interested in using the log likelihood to determine the best fitting model out of a series of models. AIC would be best, but AIC() does not work on splm objects. Further, the calculation of AIC uses log likelihood, which is usually negative.
Is there a way to interpret a positive log likelihood to determine model fit? Is a larger log likelhood still better?

Treat a positive log-likelihood the same as a negative one. Or even one equal to zero.
The same rules about deviance and degrees of freedom apply.
The likelihood is the value of the joint probability density of the data given the parameters. Probability density functions integrate to 1 over their range.
For a discrete probability distribution, this means all the probability densities must be less than one because they can't be negative and they have to sum to one. This gives rise to likelihoods less than 1, and hence log-likelihoods less than 0, eg for Poisson or Binomial models.
A continuous probability density function can have values greater than 1. For example consider a uniform distribution between 0 and 0.1 - its density value must be 10 between those values and zero elsewhere so that its area is 0.1 x 10 = 1.
A Gaussian probability distribution function has a peak value inversely related to its variance - a narrow Gaussian has a higher peak in order to satisfy the "integrates to one" rule. This means even simple linear models with narrow enough variance can have likelihood over 1 and hence positive log-likelihood.
